# Error motores Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

estoy intentando crear un "roomba" en Arduino pero hay un error, ya que el motor de las ruedas no se me enciende.

Hay conectados un sensor ultrasónico, un l9110 (para gestionar los motores), un led, una resistencia y un pulsador. También los dos motores que van al l9110.

He hecho un código y parece esta bien, pero no comprendo cuál es el error. Anteriormente me dió errores con el sensor pero ya esta solucionado. He aumentado también el voltaje para que no afecte al funcionamiento (en total 13V).

Aquí está mi código. ¿Alguien podría revisarlo y decirme si ve algún error? Muchas gracias.

```
int ledEncendido = 2;
int echoSensor = 4;
int triggerSensor = 7;
int interruptor = 8;
int motorI1 = 9;
int motorI2 = 10;
int motorD1 = 11;
int motorD2 = 12;
bool interruptorPulsado = false;
int distance;
int mover;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(interruptor, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledEncendido, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(triggerSensor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorD1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorD2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorI1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorI2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(ledEncendido, LOW); //El LED enpieza estando apagado.
}

void loop() 
{
  if (interruptorPulsado == false) //Si la variable no es false esto se omite.
  {
    while (digitalRead(interruptor) == HIGH && interruptorPulsado == false)
    {
        //No se ejecuta nada en bucle hasta que pulsamos el interruptor.
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) //Parpadeamos un led para anunciar al usuario de que se va a iniciar el dispositivo.
    {
      digitalWrite(ledEncendido, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(ledEncendido, LOW);
      delay(500);
    }
    interruptorPulsado = true; //Cambiamos el estado de la variable para que al volver a empezar el loop no se ejecute.
  }


  digitalWrite(ledEncendido, HIGH);
  mover = medirDistancia();
  
  if (mover < 10) //Si la distancia con el objeto es mayor a 100.
  {
    digitalWrite(motorD1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorD2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorI1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorI2, HIGH);
  }
}

int medirDistancia()
{
  digitalWrite(triggerSensor, LOW); //Nos aseguramos de que el sensor está en el estado correcto para empezar la medición.
  delayMicroseconds(2); //Esperamos 2 microsegundos.
  digitalWrite(triggerSensor, HIGH); //Empezamos a medir distáncia.
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(triggerSensor, LOW); //Dejamos de medir distáncia.
  long duration = pulseIn(echoSensor, HIGH); //Con "pulseIn" esperamos hasta que el pin "echo" sea "HIGH" y medimos cuanto tarda en volver a ser "LOW".
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2; /*Calculamos la distáncia medida por el sensor en cm. Multiplicamos la duración del sonido entre 0,034(velocidad
                                         del sonido en el aire) entre 2(la ida y a vuelta)*/
  Serial.println(distance);
  return distance;
}
```

Comment: Qué motores usas?

Comment: Esta línea es un poco confusa. El comentario y la condición no coinciden. Si la distancia es mayor o igual a 10 no mueves el robot. ``` mover = medirDistancia(); if (mover < 10) //Si la distancia con el objeto es mayor a 100.
{
``` Por otro lado, prueba a imprimir algo para ver si entras en esta condición y actúas sobre las salidas del motor

Comment: Un motor de engranaje. Van conectados ha una placa conectada al arduino que se llama l9110.

Comment: Lo del comentario da igual, se me había olvidado cambiarlo. En cuanto a lo de imprimir algo en consola cuando se cumple la condición, lo he hecho y siempre que es menor a 10 se imprime un mensaje.                                                                                                                 Sigo sin saber como solucionarlo.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes compartir información del cableado? y el datasheet del I9110? He encontrado información de un controlador de motor L9110, no sé si es exactamente el mismo. Por otro lado el led de la placa del controlador se enciende?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/386212)